# How to automaticaly post on Facebook page with PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to find solution for automatic posting to my funpage from PHP script, but without user prompt.

My usecase is quite simple - every friday there is event related with my funpage and I would like to post on site wall some information about it (loaded from database) using cron script written in PHP. I would like to use my account to do it.

I found a lot of articles related to autoposting but most of them are stale.

I created new FB application and few lines of code:

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '1897212530527861',
  'app_secret' => $app_secret,
  'default_access_token' => $app_access_token,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
]);

$params = [
    'link' => 'www.myurl.com',
    'message' => 'Info about the meeting',
];

$response = $fb->post('/my.funpage/feed', $params);
```

Currently I am reaching error:

> The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Might it be related to missing permissions in applciation configuration? I requested for publish_pages and manage_pages, but I can not review it while 
[there is message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3I4L.png).

Comment: I have code that posts into groups.  It requires a user token with publishing scope ~ not the app token.

Comment: You need to use a user access token if you want to post as the user (but then a different permission, and the page settings must allow it), or a page access token. I don't see you getting either of those anywhere.

Comment: How can I request / generate such token? I can't find any page about it.